# Is a constant a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Can a constant $c$ be regarded as a random variable?

Is it correct to define it as a discrete random variable X with probability mass function $P(X=c)=1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (real-valued) random variable is a function $X : \Omega \to \mathbb R$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space. Certainly given any constant $c$, we can define the associated constant function $X(\omega) = c$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$, and there's generally no confusion if we identify the number $c$ with the constant function. And indeed $X$ will have the probability mass function $P(X=c) = 1$.

The converse is not necessarily true, however. A random variable with probability mass function $P(X=c) = 1$ need not be constant. For example, if $\Omega$ is the unit interval $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, we can define
$$X(\omega) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }\omega\text{ is irrational} \\
0 & \text{if }\omega\text{ is rational} \\
\end{cases}$$
in which case $X$ has the probability mass function $P(X = 1) = 1$ but is not constant.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; such a constant random variable has characteristic function $e^{ict}$, probability density $\delta (x-c)$ (a [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)) etc.

Comment: Shouldn't the probability density be undefined? Isn't the probability distribution function is a step function for this case?

Comment: @Angelos The CDF is a step function, $\theta(x-c)$. Differentiation obtains a "PDF", albeit technically a measure instead of a function.